# Ajax call get content with url

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hello I'm using pure **javascript** for `get ajax` content without page Load.

```
document.getElementById('dashboard').addEventListener('click', dashboard);

function dashboard(){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'dashboard.php', true);

  xhr.onload = function(){
    if(this.status == 200){
        history.pushState(null, null, '#dashboard.php');
      document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    } else if(this.status = 404){
      document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'Not Found';
    }
  }
  xhr.onerror = function(){
    console.log('Request Error...');
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

This code works perfectly, but when I refresh the page manually, the content sets back to start page. If I open form page, and after refresh from hand, website show Dashboard page.

I want to stay on current page even after refresh. Thank you.

Comment: you will have to use `localStorage` or something like this

Comment: can you example me?

Comment: it isnt difficult - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: ok thank you man, i will enscript it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you are using JavaScript and ajax only but the most easiest and widely used way is to use **PHP Session Variable** since you are using get method you can do it easily. If you set a PHP session variable no matter how many times you refresh it will show the page that you want to show either by hiding or by redirecting by checking the **session variable**.You can check this link: [PHP SESSIONS](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Answer (score 1):

This code works perfectly, thank you guys!

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['c'])){
    if($_GET['c'] == 'dashboard'){
        include('dashboard.php');
    }else if($_GET['c'] == 'form'){
        include('form.php');
    }
}else{
    include('dashboard.php');
}
?>
```